# Display OP information when listing questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, information-display

Currently, when viewing [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) below each question appears only the last modifier.
Is it possible to display the OP as well?

I created a "screen shot" of what is currently presented (top row) and my proposition (bottom row)

[image: my proposition]

Showing the OP below the question may provide important information:

- when was the question asked (not just "last modified"). Is this question new or old?
- how proficient the OP is? If he/she is a veteran user (high reputation) we would expect better questions and more detailed answers. While, on  the other hand, for a novice user we might choose to give shorter and simpler answers without lengthy discussions.
- For more seasoned users, I believe SO provides a sense of community: knowing each other and expecting certain responses and replies. Seeing a question asked by one of your SO long-time "friend" might encourage oneself to try harder to answer better answers.

So, I believe that OP information provides important contextual information regarding each question, and thus it would be nice if this information will be displayed along side the "last modifier" of the question.

Comment: Only the "active" tab show this as it sort by last activity. You can browse questions via [newest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) tab or [unanswered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) where it show the "asked..." format. Personally I don't think the added value is worth it, it will clog the design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the points you stated shouldn't affect the way you respond to questions. If the question is good, it shouldn't matter *when* the question was asked or *who* asked it.

If you could add a *good* answer to the question to add value to it, just do it!